# El $ de $(function(){ no está definido

Tags: php, jquery, laravel

logré resolver parte de mi problema anterior, pero no logró resolver éste estraño error, el cual según leí, ocurre cuando jquery no está definido, pero Jquery está en la carpeta donde debería.

Estoy usando la versión más nueva de Laravel, DataTable si está instalado correctamente.

El error que detecta el navegador es:

```
"home:2 Uncaught ReferenceError: $ is not defined at home:2"
```

Este es el codigo de home que tiene problemas:

```
@section('content')
<script type="text/javascript" src="{{ URL::asset('js/jquery.js') }}"> 
</script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="{{ URL::asset('js/bootstrap.min.js') }}"></script>

<div id="Paris" class="w3-container w3-border city" style="display:none">
 <center><h2>Productos actuales</h2></center>
        <table class="table table-bordered" id="tablename">
           <thead>
              <tr>
                 <th>Id</th>
                 <th>Nombre</th>
                 <th>Precio</th>
                 <th>Empresa</th>
                 <th>Fecha de creacion</th>
                 <th>Fecha de actualizacion</th>
              </tr>
           </thead>
        </table>
@stop
</div>

    <script>
     $(function(){
           $('#tablename').DataTable({
           processing: true,
           serverSide: true,
           url: '{{ route('home/getRes') }}', //Esto va a la ruta web.php
           columns: [
            {data: 'id'},
            {data: 'nombre'},
            {data: 'precio'},
            {data: 'empresa'},
            {data: 'created_at'},
            {data: 'updated_at'}
            ]
        });
     });
     </script>
```

Éste es el código al cual se contecta en HomeController.

```
return Datatables::of(Product::query())->toJson()->make(true);
```

Aquí está el código de la ruta:

```
Route::get('home/getRes', 'HomeController@getRes')->name('home/getRes');
```

Lo que tengo en Product

```
<?php

namespace App;

use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;

class Product extends Model
{
 protected $fillable = ['nombre', 'precio', 'empresa'];
 protected $table =  'products';
 protected $primaryKey = 'id';

}
```

Comment: revisa en la pestaña network de Chrome devtools a qué scripts está llamando. Revisa la fuente del HTML usando CTRL+U. Yo empezaría por eso.

Comment: Hice eso, encontré que el script con $function por alguna razón aparce de primero y que va a una dirección http://localhost/laravel/test/public/home/getRes, la cual si coloco en mi barra de busqueda obtengo un error "Method Illuminate\Http\JsonResponse::make does not exist."

Comment: Tratastes de colocar el llamado de la libreria al final justo antes de cerrar el body?

Comment: Lo hice, ahora tengo el error "jQuery.Deferred exception: $(...).DataTable is not a function TypeError: $(...).DataTable is not a function"